# Hide div on click and show another div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a bootstrap modal. There are two bootstrap tabs in that modal. "Work" button is the active tab. "Hire" button is the other tab. This modal wrapped with .col-md-8 class with these styles

```
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-8 {
      width: 87%;
      margin-top: 37px;
      margin-bottom: 31px;
    }
  }
```

The problem is that the "Hire" tab content has a higher width than "Work" content. So it's looking his way.

[image]

I need to show "Hire" tab original width when someone click "Hire" tab. I know this happened because I wrapped with .col-md-8 class. Don't have any option to hide that main class on click and show "Hire" tab original width? I'm using meteor and react.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this the best way is to use jquery.

You have to give id to work, hire button and work-content and hire-content.

for e.g.

HTML:

```
<button id="work-btn">Work</button> <button id="hire-btn">Hire</button>
<div id="work-content"> The content goes here </div>
<div id="hire-content"> The content goes here </div>
```

CSS:

```
.hire-content {
 display:none; 
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#hire-btn").click(function() {
   $("#work-content").hide();
   $("#hire-content").show(); 
 });
});
```

Hope this helps. If you have any query feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase width of **modal-dialog** by adding class.you can add class **modal-lg**. then you can expand width of modal when clicking Hire tab.

Comment: I don't need to increase width it's parent element.